# VBA match a range in a range

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to match if any value in a range is present in another range. Ordinarily you would have to run your match function in a loop

```
For Each text in range
    Match(text,range,type)
Next text
```

so is it possible to perform this search without the loop? like

```
Match(source range, search range, type)
```

> example: if you had a range with John, mary, ann. then you got 3 sheets with 100 names. You would like to know if any of the names in the source range appear in the tables in the other sheets?

Comment: Load the search items into a memory array loop the sheets and the memory array doing the matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without VBA we would use something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1:A5,B1:B5)) > 0
```

So with VBA, we could just `EVALUATE()` something like this.

*(this requires lists of the same size, so extend the shorter list)*

```
Sub KountKommon()
    x = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1:A6,B1:B6))")
    MsgBox "there are " & x & " items in common"
End Sub
```

[image]